# Lenovo U550 USB 3.0 enabled

Tags: windows-7, windows

Which USB ports on my Lenoovo U550 laptop are 3.0 enabled? I want to purchase an external portable hard drive and am checking ratings. They refer to USB 3.0 enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the plastic part inside the USB port. It should be white in USB 1.1/2.0 and blue in USB 3.0 ports.

Another way to check it is simply to connect a USB 3.0-enabled external hard drive to different ports and check speeds when copying big files.

Comment: Also Windows will tell you if you connected USB3.0 into USB 2.0 ports and telling you that the device can run faster if moved to a different port